# Get And Sort In Array Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have document like this

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "myarray": [
        {
            "_id": "4",
            "name": "d",
            "order": 4
        },
        {
            "_id": "1",
            "name": "a",
            "order": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "2",
            "name": "b",
            "order": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

i want to see sort data in array by order when get from db
i am trying some query like below but it seems not OK and nothing changed

```
 db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$myarray"},{$project: {orders:"$myarray.order"}},{$group: {_id:"$_id",min:{$min: "$orders"}}},{$sort: {min:1}}])

db.myarray.find({},{$sort:{"myarray.order":-1}})
db.collection.find({"_id":"1"}).sort({"myarray.order":1})
```

what is correct query?

I need something like this

```
db.collection.find({"_id":"1"}).sort({"myarray.order":1})
```

Comment: sorry it's 

 
 db.myarray.find().sort( { order: 1 } )

Comment: The [**Aggregation Framework**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) works well for such queries, why don't you try `db.collection.aggregate({ $unwind: '$myarray' }, { $sort: {'myarray.order': -1 }})`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipelines

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$myarray" }, 
    { "$sort": { "myarray.order": 1 }}, 
    { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "myarray": { "$push": "$myarray" }}}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort in a response and not permanently:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": 1 } },
    { "$unwind": "$myarray" },
    { "$sort": { "myarray.order": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "myarray": { "$push": "$myarray" }
    }}
])
```

To alter permanently:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": 1 }, 
    { "$push": { "myarray": { "$each": [], "sort": { "order": 1 } } }},
    { "multi": true }
)
```

If this is what you generally want then your best option is generally to [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) the array as you [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) a new element or elements via [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) as another modifier.

Of course if you [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) elements from the array the "current" syntax requires another query to be issued in order to sort the array just as is already shown.

It's generally better to keep your results in the order you expect, rather than order them in post processing, as the latter will always come at a cost that is greater than the former approach.

Comment: it is ok but i need to get document with _id 1 and sort it's array data

Comment: @user298582 That is not a problem, see the edited information. The real issue as I see it is making the decision to either keep the arrays sorted or do it on request. Unless you change the sorting pattern all the time the former makes sense.