# How to sort a MongoDB document by its subdocument fields

Tags: json, mongodb, sorting, bson

I'm trying to order the following document but I don't get the way to do it.
I need help to **sort** the following MongoDB document by the field **attributes.k** is order (and order by v).

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55174192825a674422d29422"),        
        "attributes" : [
                {
                        "k" : "order",                        
                        "v" : "2"
                },
                {
                        "k" : "image",                        
                        "v" : "550f3232f2bb54ac057883ab"
                }
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("551741a2825a674422d29423"),  
        "attributes" : [
                {
                        "k" : "order",                        
                        "v" : "1"
                },
                {
                        "k" : "image",                        
                        "v" : "550f3283f2bb54ac057883b2"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Why don't give a different name to attribute.k is order compare to the attribute.k is image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get And Sort In Array Mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076213/get-and-sort-in-array-mongodb)

Comment: Thanks to @kenshinji. You give a new approach to solve the problem.

Comment: @JoseCarlos you are welcome, I am a newbie to MongoDB :p